# Can a body, made of semi-light material, theoretically float on water (ocean) if it has enough airtight space under it? What are the risks?

Tags: water, fluid-statics, density, buoyancy

[image]Hello scientists and amateurs,
Basically, if I put a quite big airtight container on water and use it as a type of float to wander around ocean (Let's say pretty big, size of a half a football field). Bottom of it is exposed to water, top is freely floating. We are also facing waves, winds and all kinds of ocean horrors. Theoretically would the float be successful? I understand there would be risks of winds, hence waves too, but if the object itself is pretty huge(airtight bottom would be rather high too), would it not just float around no matter the conditions or harsh environment?
Any idea which physics topics to research and what concepts to understand to get a hang of this?
Thank you for your opinions and answers everyone!

EDIT: thank you first of all for answers everyone!
It is not called a boat, it is a design that works specifically to hold solar panels and is on water, ocean or etc(lakes, water basins).
I am including a picture and expanding my question: Will it survive wave impact if the structure is rather big. Basically you can research them as floating solar panels. Just this design is a bit different than regular ones hence i was curious what people think about its capability to withstand waves n storms.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you say a large, airtight container, that would be able to float on water, could it be you are talking about a ship? These are usually not even airtight, but the ship can exchange air with the surrounding, while being waterproof is enough so they can float.

Comment: An aircraft carrier is pretty big--even bigger than half a football field. Aircraft carriers are not designed to be air tight, but if you sealed all of the hatches...

Comment: A surfaced submarine with its hatches closed is air tight.

Comment: It's called a boat.  What are you asking?

Comment: You're describing a wet diving bell, which needs to be weighted down or else float.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously boats float. The basic structure of a boat is a top-open box resting in the water at some depth. The usual [condition of stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy#Static_stability) is that the centre of gravity is below the centre of buoyancy (the centre of mass of the displaced water), although [some hull shapes can get around it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacentric_height). The key thing is that if the hull deviates from vertical, gravity and buoyancy forces produce a torque that restores it towards vertical.

[image]
*A floating boat, with centre of gravity (yellow) and centre of buoyancy (green). If tilted, it restores itself.*

But the question is about the reverse situation: an upside-down airtight box that contains some air under pressure keeping the box afloat. The situation is still the same in a sense: there is displaced water, creating a centre of buoyancy, and there is a centre of gravity... easily above it. So if you use a rather flat box the result will be that when it tilts, the resulting torque will make it tilt more. Before long air will start escaping, and it sinks.

[image]
*A floating box. The centre of gravity is above the centre of buoyancy. When tilted the turning moment increases the tilt.*

Now, imagine that the box is pretty light and has very long edges (like a beer glass or a floating test tube). Then a smallish amount of air can be trapped inside and still keep it afloat. But the long edges bring down the centre of gravity below the centre of buoyancy and it will be stable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would float, but it will most likely break at some point of size.
Physical principles are buoyancy, ship stability criteria, material strength/stress, ocean waves (amplitude > 10m, wavelength length 0-130m) and wind. The internal stress of the container would become quite high, think of long bar only supported at every 50m (or whatever). Large ponton (flexible connections of various (airtight) containers or floating bodies) can serve e.g. as an airfield for aircraft fighter jets (real applications). Here I would see no real restriction of size, besides money to build.